# Cannot get master address from sentinel running @myIpaddress:6379

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel

I'm working on implementing the master slave using sentinels in Redis with spring boot application. And while creating the JedisSentinelPool using sentinels I'm getting the following error

> Cannot get master address from sentinel running @myIpaddress:6379

Below is the code.

```
        final String MASTER_NAME = "mymaster";
        final String PASSWORD = "empower";
        final Set sentinels;

        sentinels = new HashSet();
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:6379");
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:2222");
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:3333");

        JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(MASTER_NAME, sentinels);
```

My question is how do I run the sentinels and how do I fix this issue. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**bind your `ip address` to 127.0.0.1**

```
# Example sentinel.conf
# By default Sentinel will not be reachable from interfaces different than
# localhost, either use the 'bind' directive to bind to a list of network
# interfaces, or disable protected mode with "protected-mode no" by
# adding it to this configuration file.
#
# Before doing that MAKE SURE the instance is protected from the outside
# world via firewalling or other means.
#
# For example you may use one of the following:
#
bind 10.10.21.192 127.0.0.1
```